# SELECT * users who are a certain age

Tags: mysql, sql

In the `users` table I have a field called `dob` which stores the date of birth of the user in this format:

```
1959-04-02
```

Anyway I would like to SELECT all users who are 18 and 19 years old. This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE dob BETWEEN '1993-10-30' AND '1994-10-30'
```

But it only seems to select mostly 18 year olds and some (but not all) 19 year olds. I have a bunch of test users in the db and the number of 18 and 19 year olds are equal. Yet this query yields about 90% 18 year olds and about 10% 19 year olds. Why?

Comment: your field is a Date field right? not a string?

Comment: do like this : SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE dob >= '1993-10-30' AND dob <= '1994-10-30'

Comment: @kidz same, I think the problem is due to the issue Norla mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People who are between 18 and 19 years old encompass a range of birthdates over 2 years.  Your query only covers 1 year.  Consider reworking your logic.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE dob BETWEEN 
    CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR 
    AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR
```

Technically that will include people who turn 20 today. You can change the `interval` to a `DATE_ADD` and be more precise if you'd like.

This is a bit cleaner, because you don't need to rework the two birthdays in PHP (or god forbid, manually) each time.

Comment: I like the idea of not having to work out the dates in PHP which is what I was doing. But this query results in this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'YEARS AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEARS LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4`

Comment: It might need to be `YEAR` (singular) instead of `YEARS` (plural). Also, given that this is a date field rather than a timestamp field (which is what I usually use) I'm not sure if you need quotes around it. I don't think so, but I would test.

Comment: `YEAR` got rid of the syntax error but returned 0 rows even though I have 18 and 19 year olds in the table.

Comment: @TK123 I know this is really old, but I wanted to make a comment for anyone (like myself) who found this. You must have the bigger date, first. So `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR`

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but David Grenier's answer will work if you put the greater interval first (and YEAR not YEARS, as pointed out)

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE dob BETWEEN 
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR 
AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
```